# The XAML code expect my Command in different VM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, viewmodel

On the main window xaml, I have a Frame that will host 2 pages, like this

```
<Window x:Class="Monitor.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" FontSize="14">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="48"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Frame Content="Frame" Grid.Row="1" Source="/Monitor;component/Views/Pages/GroupPage.xaml"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

On the first page (GroupPage.xaml) xaml code is

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <VM:GroupPageVM />
</Page.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="GroupsOfItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupsOfItems}">
        <ItemsControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <WrapPanel  Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"                             
                            FlowDirection="LeftToRight" IsItemsHost="true">
                </WrapPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Template>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="3"                                            
                        Content="{Binding Name}" 
                        Width="1.2in" Height=".75in" FontSize="14" 
                        Command="{Binding Path=GroupSelectedCommand }"
                        CommandParameter= "{Binding}"
                        />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

</Grid>
```

The GroupPageVM is the VM for this page. GroupsOfItems is a collection of VM for groups. Each Group VM has a Name where I bind it for the content of a button that represent for that group. So on the screen, I will see a collection of buttons in a WrapPanel. Everything display correctly.

Now the issue come with the command that handle the click on the button, the code expect I put my Command (GroupSelectedCommand) and its execute function inside the VM of the Group, instead in the MainWindow VM.

Can someone explain why?
If it is how it suppose to work, how do I put the command in the MainWindow VM? because without that I cannot access to the Frame that host the pages or any NavigationService to go to page 2 by clicking on one of those buttons.

(My simple goal is clicking on a button that represent a group, and it will navigate to a page to display items in that group)

Comment: Does your code work at the moment? Does clicking on the templated Button fire the GroupSelectedCommand, and if so which ViewModel did you implement that Command in?

Comment: Yes, the code works, just not the way I wanted thought. But Bell's answer gave me some direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have bound `GroupsOfItems` as the `ItemsSource` of the `ItemsControl`. Inside GroupsOfItems you have `GroupVM` objects. So each item inside the `ItemsControl` will be holding a `GroupVM` object. Also the `DataTemplate` defined will be representing the `GroupVM` object. Thus the Command will be expected inside `GroupVM` object.

To access parent DataContext, you can try giving `ElementName` as shown below,

```
 Command="{Binding DataContext.GroupSelectedCommand, ElementName=GroupsOfItemsControl }"
```

In the above code the button will try to take the Command from the DataContext of ItemsControl which is the `GroupPageVM`